# How can i create a 3d curve/saddle shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

I have tried and failed to use the *Bezier Curve* tool to create a 3D saddle shape only managing to bend a plane in one direction.

Is this the best way to do so and how should I go about doing it?

This is the shape i'm trying to create:

[image: picture from http://erikdemaine.org/hypar/]

Thanks

Comment: can you add a picture of what you want to create? Are you struggling with trying to get the plane to bend "around the horse" and arch front to back?

Comment: I guess a subdivided plane driven by a lattice modifier would do the job perfectly, I'll make you a more detailed  answer later.

Answer (score 11):

Bezier curves are not the proper tool for this, curves are useful mainly for extrusion based geometries, or sections-swept-along-paths shapes.

NURBS surfaces may be closer to what you need, though they will require some considerable manual modeling work, and they are a half-baked tool in Blender that wont help much.

You may also model this manually using meshes and subdivisions, but again will require a lot of manual modelling and not necessarily yield a mathematically accurate surface.

The best way to model such thing is using the builtin addon *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* Python script

Start by opening *File > User Preferences > Addons* then search for `Extra` and activate the *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* addon.

Then in the *3D View* press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Add > Mesh > Math Function > Z Math Function*

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point) the mathematical function for a simple Saddle Point surface is `Z = X^2 - Y^2` so in the operator properties change the input formula to the desired function using Python notation which should be `(x**2 - Y**2)`

[image: Blender Saddle Point Z function]

Answer (score 1):

If you're just going for that look, and don't need mathematical precision,
Subdivide a plane then add a Simple Deform modifier using a sphere.

Do this twice.  Once along the X-axis, and once along the Y-axis.

Set the Deform Angle positive for one of 'em,
and negative for the other.

You can see the technique illustrated here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x77mvrmI0ck