# normal vector calculation on a surface

Tags: mesh, mathematics

Given a function like f(x,y,z)=constant like an isosurface, 
I was wondering if there is any way to:

1) create a mesh and save the coordinates of the points into a separate file?

2) calculate the normal vector at each of these (mesh created) points and save them in a separate file?

Thanks in advance for your reply and comments.
Cheers

Comment: Are any of these anywhere near what you need? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73741/how-can-i-create-a-3d-curve-saddle-shape/73752#73752 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74410/graph-in-blender-a-function-of-two-variables/74412#74412

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen these two posts before. However, in my equation, it is not easy to solve z as a function of x and y. This is why I want to draw it as an isosurface. say (cos(x)cos(y)sin(z)=1). This equation is easy to solve, but it is just an example to clarify :-). Besides, I do not know how to calculate the normal vectors using this add-on. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: The normals would have to be read from the resulting mesh I believe, not related to the addon itself. You would probably need to devise some sort of python script for that though, and the accuracy would probably always be limited to the initial level of detail the mesh was created with.

Comment: Thanks Duarte, are you aware of any python module which could do these? i.e. read a file with coordinates on the surface + the analytical expression of the surface, and then calculate the normal vectors for each point? Please have a look at this: I want these on a surface like this: http://matkcy.github.io/surface.html

Comment: Are those colors representations all you need? That can be easily achieved with a simple shader in Blender.

Comment: no, I want to calculate the normal vectors on all the vertices on a surface like that picture.