# particle simulation distribution on a surface using the analytical expression

Tags: mesh, mathematics

Not sure if this is possible with Blender or not.
I have a collection of particles all with the same mass and same charge.
I want to distribute them on a surface which I have the analytical expression for; e.g. $f(x,y,z)=\text{constant}$.

Can I get the optimized distribution of these particles on the given surface in Blender?

Thanks in advance for your reply and comments,
Cheers

Comment: You can generate a surface from said mathematical expression as described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74410/graph-in-blender-a-function-of-two-variables) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73741/how-can-i-create-a-3d-curve-saddle-shape). You can also use resulting shapes to emit particles from their surface using a particle system. I'm not sure what "*same mass and same charge*" and "*optimized distribution of these particles*" means though, so not sure if Blender's particle system has the features or functions for what you require.