# How can I make this surface in blender...?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, subdivision-surface, extrude, nurbs-surface

[image]

How can I make a surface like this....? I made this using nurbs in maya. Please Help. Thank You :)

Comment: related: [How can i create a 3d curve/saddle shape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73741/how-can-i-create-a-3d-curve-saddle-shape)

Answer (score 4):

There is basic support of NURBs surfaces in Blender. Basic is the keyword here. Check docs for detailed information about them: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/surfaces/introduction.html

[image: overview]

In this example I've started with **Surface NURBs Curve** (marked as 1., red color) after moving and subdividing to achieve desired shape I've **Duplicate** it and made its reflection on X axis - <kbd>S</kbd>><kbd>X</kbd>>-1. Than I've selected both **Curves** and **made a segment** - <kbd>F</kbd>. After some more tweaking individual vertices, subdividing surface and selecting **Endpoint on V** this is a result.

Also I've added **Subdivision Surface Modifier**.

In conclusion, it is possible, but it's really painful in Blender as it is lacking many mesh modeling tools. Read the docs and maybe you will be happy with them.