# How can I turn this math formula into a 3d model?

Tags: python, 3d-printing, command-line

how can i turn a 3d model made in surfer into a 3d file that i can print

Comment: Yes. Just start a new model in Blender.  There are plenty of tutorials available on the web site that rhymes with noonube.  There are even simple snow man tutorials.  Surfer is not necessary for this simple model.  Tutorials ...Blender Mesh Modeling.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74410/graph-in-blender-a-function-of-two-variables/74412#74412 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73741/how-can-i-create-a-3d-curve-saddle-shape/73752#73752

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could, but I can't think of efficient way of doing it. Your snowman is a procedural geometry, when most of the 3d computer graphics are based on triangles.
I think problem will be the precision, especially those equations describe volume rather than surface.
I've made quick test for the lemon from surfer example:

```
import bpy
import math

for x_ in range (-20,20):
    for y_ in range (-20,20):
        for z_ in range (-20,20):
            x = x_*0.05
            y = y_*0.05
            z = z_*0.05
            left = x**2 + z**2
            right = y**3*(1-y)**3

            if left-right<=0.05:
                bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments=3, ring_count=3, radius=0.005, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(x, y, z))
```

you could probably generate a point cloud, and then use Meshlab or CloudCompare to reconstruct the mesh from point cloud